# signOut in NextJS with Firebase Authentication does not Work

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, next.js, firebase-authentication

Have been trying to sign out the user after pressing sign out from navbar and other pages but the user stays same.

Here is the AuthContext File I have been using.

```
import React, {
  useContext,
  createContext,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useMemo,
} from "react";
import {
  confirmPasswordReset,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  FacebookAuthProvider,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithPopup,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db } from "../config/firebase";
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  onSnapshot,
  query,
  setDoc,
  where,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const AuthContext = createContext({
  currentUser: null,
  signInWithGoogle: () => Promise,
  login: () => Promise,
  register: () => Promise,
  logout: () => Promise,
  loading: false,
});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export default function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [initalLoading, setInitialLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [uniqueId, setUniqueId] = useState(null);
  const route = useRouter();

  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        setLoading(true);
        route.push("/");
      }
      setInitialLoading(false);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

   
  const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      // const result = await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
      const user = result.user;
      const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
      const docs = await getDocs(q);
      if (docs.docs.length === 0) {
        await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
          uid: user.uid,
          name: user.displayName,
          authProvider: "facebook",
          email: user.email,
        });
      }
      console.log(result.user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const signInWithFacebook = async () => {
    try {
      const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
      provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      const user = result.user;
      const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
      const docs = await getDocs(q);
      if (docs.docs.length === 0) {
        await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
          uid: user.uid,
          name: user.displayName,
          authProvider: "google",
          email: user.email,
        });
      }
      console.log(result.user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


  const logout = async () => {
    try {
      setCurrentUser(null)
      await signOut(auth)
      return true
    }
    catch (error) {
      return false
    }
  }

  const memoedValue = useMemo(() => ({
    currentUser,
    signInWithGoogle,
    logout,
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    loading,
    signInWithFacebook,
  }));

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={memoedValue}>
      {!initalLoading && children}
     </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**

Here is the Firebase Config File

**

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

// // Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: XXX,
  authDomain: XXX,
  projectId: XXX,
  storageBucket: XXX,
  messagingSenderId: XXX,
  appId: XXX,
  measurementId: XXX,
};

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { app, auth, db, storage };
```

Comment: Also, seems like the "signOut" function is failing in any browser such as chrome and safari

Comment: check the response status of await signOut(auth).

Comment: You are right. Not getting any logs

Comment: What Firebase Web SDK version are you using? Could you create a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Your code implementation is correct. the only issue might be the `firebaseConfig`. You do not have `databaseURL:` property.

```
databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
```